# Unable to catch event emitted from child component in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-components

I am sorry for my newbie question, I am trying to emit an event from a child to a parent component using an `@Output` `EventEmitter`. I am unable to catch the event in my parent component.

***Child Component***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-attachment',
  templateUrl: './new-attachment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-attachment.component.css']
})
class NewAttachmentComponent {
  @Input('attachment') attachment: any;
  @Output() doneEditingAttachment:EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  submit() {
    console.log('done editing child');
    this.doneEditingAttachment.emit(true);
  }
}
```

***Parent Component***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-article',
  templateUrl: './new-article.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-article.component.css']
})
class NewArticleComponent {
   newAttachment: any = {};
   doneEditingAttachment($event) {
     console.log('done editing parent ', $event);
   }
}
```

I expected to have

> done editing child

And a

> done editing parent

But I only got *done editing child*

Comment: how does the html look like?

Comment: @Sajeetharan <app-new-attachment [hidden]="!toggleNewAttachment" [attachment]="newAttachment"></app-new-attachment> I already figured it out: I forgot to add the event in the child html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to actually have a binding to the event of the child using the `(eventName)` notation:

```
<app-new-attachment [attachment]="newAttachment" (doneEditingAttachment)="doneEditingAttachment($event)"></app-new-attachment>
```

Comment: (doneEditingAttachment)="doneEditingAttachment($event)"

Comment: I don't know why the answer is marked as correct but the '$event' parameter must be present in the method 

i.e.

<app-new-attachment [attachment]="newAttachment" (doneEditingAttachment)="doneEditingAttachment($event)"></app-new-attachment>

Comment: If the '$event' param is not given, it will give an error as 'undefined'. Edited the main answer.

Comment: @neekheel it depends if you want to actually use the value from the `$event`. So depending on the function you call, you add the `$event` or not

Comment: Yup, particularly, in this case, there should be '$event' param but then you are correct if data is not in use we can skip the '$event' param

Answer (score 1):

Based on the commnet you need this,

```
<app-new-attachment [attachment]="newAttachment" (doneEditingAttachment)="submit()"></app-new-attachment>
```

Comment: (doneEditingAttachment)="doneEditingAttachment($event)"

Comment: cool, instead of posting new answer, you could have marked above or mine